# Como declarar função objetivo no Python contendo a mesma variável porém para intervalos diferentes?

Tags: python

Possuo uma variável binária x[i][j][t] definida no intervalo

```
for i in dat.I for j in dat.I if i != j for t in range(len(dat.H[0]) + 1)
```

Necessito que tal variável seja multiplicada por um parâmetro -Lambda[i][t] em uma determinada situação e que a variável x[j][i][t] (alterando-se a ordem dos índices) seja multiplicada por um parâmetro Lambda[i][t] considerando os seguintes somatórios:

```
-Lambda[i][t] for i in dat.I for j in dat.I if i != j for t in range(dat.p[i][0] + dat.SETUP[i][j][0],min(len(dat.H[0]) - dat.p[i][0] + 1,len(dat.H[0]) - dat.p[j][0] + 1))
```

e

```
Lambda[i][t] for j in dat.I for i in dat.I if i != j for t in range(dat.p[j][0] + dat.SETUP[j][i][0],min(len(dat.H[0]) - dat.p[i][0] + 1,len(dat.H[0]) - dat.p[j][0] + 1))
```

No entanto, quando declaro essa função objetivo tenho o seguinte erro:

```
cplex.exceptions.errors.CplexError: Inconsistent arguments
```

Alguém pode me ajudar? Segue abaixo parte do código que causa o erro:

```
IT = [(i,j,t) for i in dat.I for j in dat.I if i != j for t in range(len(dat.H[0]) + 1)]
nx = ["x(" + str(i) + "," + str(j) + "," + str(t) + ")" for i in dat.I for j in dat.I if i != j for t in range(len(dat.H[0]) + 1)]

sp.variables.add(obj = [-Lambda[i][t] for i in dat.I for j in dat.I if i != j for t in range(dat.p[i][0] + dat.SETUP[i][j][0],min(len(dat.H[0]) - dat.p[i][0] + 1,len(dat.H[0]) - dat.p[j][0] + 1))],\
                    types = ['B'] * len(IT),\
                    names = nx) #Variável x binária

sp.variables.add(obj = [Lambda[i][t] for j in dat.I for i in dat.I if i != j for t in range(dat.p[j][0] + dat.SETUP[j][i][0],min(len(dat.H[0]) - dat.p[i][0] + 1,len(dat.H[0]) - dat.p[j][0] + 1))],\
                    types = ['B'] * len(IT),\
                    names = nx) #Variável x binária
```

Obs.: Os somatórios consistem em "subconjuntos" da variável x[i][j][t] inicial.